# .bash_completion file in $HOME prevents logging in

Tags: bash, bashrc

Since Mint 18.3, the `bash_completion` stuff in `/etc/` is disabled. To re-enable it, I created a `~/.bash_completion` file containing the following:

```
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```

I then source this from my `~/.bashrc` file.

*Note: `~/.bash_completion` is actually a symlink to `~/Source/dotfiles/bash_completion`.*

When I open another terminal window, it freezes and doesn't display a shell prompt until I press Ctrl+C.

Similarly, if I run `source /etc/bash_completion`, I get the same behaviour.

Running it with `set -x` suggests that it might be entering an infinite loop.

I've searched in `/etc/` and can't find anywhere that sources `~/.bash_completion`.

What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further searching reveals the `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` file, which sources the `~/.bash_completion` file.

Hence the infinite loop.

It would appear that `~/.bash_completion` is intended for custom completions, **not** as a way to separate your `.bashrc` file into self-contained pieces.

Just put the script for loading bash completions somewhere in `~/.bashrc` and call it done.